# How to use JRDataSource for jasper reports

Tags: java, spring, jasper-reports

Previously I am sending the connection object to the *`fillReport()`* of *`JasperFillManager`* class. It is working fine and it is generating the data also. The below is the code I am using for database connection.

```
Connection conn = null; 
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
conn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname", "username", "password");
```

But now I don't want to pass the connection object to the *`fillReport()`* instead I want to pass the JRDataSource. How can I achieve this? How to configure this *`JRDataSource`* in my spring configuration file with mysql database information? Can any one please tell me.

I am using `iReport 4.5.0` and `Spring 3.0.5 RELEASE`. If you want anymore information I will give you.

Comment: Hi,Can any one give me the reply for the questions i asked in this forum please.Till now i posted 3 questions.I didnt get even a single reply also.I strucked up over here from 3 days and i am expecting the answer from this forum.But i am not at all getting the reply.If this is not the correct place to post this type of problems then you just give me the url where to post.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the result set from database with the conn. Then you will use JRResultSetDataSource to instantiate a data source.

```
        Connection con = getConnection();
        PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement(jdbcString.toString());
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
        jrDataSource = new JRResultSetDataSource(rs);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
JasperReport report 
   = (JasperReport)JRLoader.loadObject(
       "F:\\Tomcat 7.0\\webapps\\ivmreports\\jasper\\FailedInsertionEventsPDF.jasper");
// Map<String, Object> parameterMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, parameterMap, reportData);
```

Here reportdata is `JRDatasource`